# Why double bottom border?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

I'm asking you to help me for solving this mysterious issue:
When I visit this web page http://www.legrandclub.net/members using IE8 it's displayed a double border bottom below search field. How is it possible? I've checked a lot of times CSS rules but I haven't found any rules that can be the reason of this issue.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First search the following lines. It's invalid to redefine the same id.

```
<div id="container">
<div id="content">


<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
```

line 1033 `tr` is not finished properly

also line 1059 `</div>` this closing div appear to be not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple problems with your markup which could be causing the problem.

1. Only use an id once. @eric-fortis said it right.
2. You have a `table` inside of a `div` inside of a `form`. Use tables only when you want to show an actual table, and if you're going to use a table, make sure to close the table! (`</table>`)
3. You have a `form` inside a `form`, this will never fly.
4. Your id usage is confusing. If I can't come in and find the problem that means no one on your team can (yourself included).

Once you fix those problems you might be able to find the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Both Eric Fortis and citizen conn have good answers ... the more general answer is to upload or paste your code to http://validator.w3.org/ or point the validator at your page's URL.

I'm not a nit-picker for 100% correct validation, but your HTML **structure** needs to be valid or you'll have no end of CSS mysteries.

---

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.legrandclub.net%2Fmembers&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Validation Output: 7 Errors

Comment: and using a good editor, to keep track of the indenting and basic syntax